# Apache HTTPS reverse proxy to HTTP

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, centos7

I can't find the solution to my request, here is what I want to do :

1. The HTTPS stream arrives on my server from my client's site (of which I do not have the certificate): https://clientwebsite.com
2. Afterwards I want to send this HTTPS stream to a website that **doesn't accept** HTTPS. So I send it in HTTP : http://api-website.com

My problem is... I don't know and I don't find how I can do that with **Apache** on **Centos 7**

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with [Pound](https://www.apsis.ch/pound.html) as my reverse HTTPS/HTTP proxy